# 'return BadRequest' ignores ExceptionFilter

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

The subject pretty much sums it up. I have an ExceptionFilter which forces developers in the project to throw only one type of exception which it allows through, any other exception is converted to a generic 500 exception. Whenever a WebApi controller method does 'return BadRequest('some message')' however, it doesn't go through the exception filter.

The problem is that I have to adhere to a specification in creating the Api. The specification states that things like BadRequest (and other http error states) have to have a custom json message in the response. Throwing an exception works, but returning a BadRequest doesn't. Any ideas around this?

ps. I know I can do this in an ActionFilter, but that feels awkward, generating exception responses in two places.

Simple test example from my controller. (doesn't do anything useful but reproduces the problem). Whenever I call this method with a value higher than 100 it returns a bad request and doesn't go through my ExceptionFilter:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("values/{count}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetValues(int count)
{
  int max = 100;

  if (count > max)
  {
    return BadRequest("'count' exceeded the maximum value of " + max);
  }

  var result = new List<string>();

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    result.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
  }

  return Ok(result);
}
```

This code DOES go through the ExceptionFilter (and is converted to a generic 500):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("unhandledexception/{httpError}")]
public void UnhandledException(int httpError)
{
  throw new Exception("This is a thrown exception for testing purposes with http code " + httpError);
}
```

This ALSO goes through the ExceptionFilter (and there it serializes to my custom json):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("handledexception/{httpError}")]
public void HandledException(int httpError)
{
  var error = new CustomApplicationError(httpError, 
    "Handled exception! Your input or request was wrong, " +
    "or something else, and now I'm telling you about it!");

  throw new HandledException(httpError, error, Request);
}
```

ExceptionFilter:

```
public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var task = base.OnExceptionAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);

  return task.ContinueWith((t) =>
  {
    var handledException = actionExecutedContext.Exception as HandledException;

    if (handledException != null)
    {
      // <snip> serialize and set to response
    }
    else
    {
      // <snip> create generic 500 and set to response
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: post you controller code.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis. There you go. Thx.

Comment: where do you write this methods like HandledException ?

Comment: It's in a TestController. To test my actionfilters and exceptionfilter.

Comment: you could have better create a custom exception filter attribute like this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Comment: That's what I did. Was that ambiguous? I say so in the first line of my post.

Comment: your code doesn't look like you create a custom exception filter.

Comment: I don't know how it matters. Since I say I have created an ExceptionFilter and the code doesn't break there. But I've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return BadRequest
```

doesn't throw an exception and that is why that is not going through the exception filter.

All it does is it creates a BadRequestResult which is an implementation of IHttpActionResult that sets the status code to 500 and create the HttpResponseMessage.

I had the same need for NotFound, what I did was:

1. Create a new implementation of IHttpActionResult with my custom logic

```
    public class NotFoundWithMessageResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly string message;

        public NotFoundWithMessageResult(string message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //your code goes here
        }
    }
```

2. Create a ControllerBase where I create the method

```
protected internal NotFoundWithMessageResult NotFound(string message, params object[] args)
{
       return new NotFoundWithMessageResult(string.Format(message, args));
}
```

3. Use it like this

```
if (x == null)
{
    return NotFound("The x id {0} was not found.", id);
}
```